# How to change 4 ImageView resources on every Click?

Tags: java, onclick, android-imageview

this is my first question here so I apologize in advance for any question format mistakes. I am trying to make a sound quiz with the sounds of a game. The idea is for the user to click on the button (round speaker icon) and play the sound. Then, choose one of the four images that correspond to the icon of that sound. [App layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZrsF.png) On every click on one of the ImageViews all four ImageViews should change the resources. However, when I click on any of those ImageViews the app becomes really slow and I get the dialog asking me to wait for it to respond or click OK to close it.
The CPU monitor shows really high percentage at that moment. [memory and CPU usage monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBV6t.png) But, I do not get any Memory Out of Bounds Exception.
This is the code of my Array and ArrayLists
`int chosenSound;

int locationOfCorrectAnswer = 0;

Integer[] answers = new Integer[4];

ArrayList<Integer> sounds = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.<Integer>asList(R.raw.dismember, R.raw.duel, R.raw.glimpse, R.raw.reapers_scythe, R.raw.vacuum));

ArrayList<Integer> icons = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.<Integer>asList(R.drawable.dismember, R.drawable.duel, R.drawable.glimpse, R.drawable.reapers_schyte, R.drawable.vacuum));`
And this is the method for generating new question:

```
public void generateQuestion() {


    Random random = new Random();
    chosenSound = random.nextInt(sounds.size());

    if (alreadyUsedSounds.size() == icons.size()) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You used all the sounds!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {

        while (alreadyUsedSounds.contains(icons.get(chosenSound))) {
            chosenSound = random.nextInt(sounds.size());
        }
    }
    locationOfCorrectAnswer = random.nextInt(4);
    int incorrectAnswerLocation;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i == locationOfCorrectAnswer) {

            answers[i] = icons.get(chosenSound);

        } else {

            incorrectAnswerLocation = random.nextInt(sounds.size());

            while (incorrectAnswerLocation == chosenSound || Arrays.asList(answers).contains(icons.get(incorrectAnswerLocation))) {
                incorrectAnswerLocation = random.nextInt(sounds.size());
            }


            answers[i] = icons.get(incorrectAnswerLocation);
        }
    }
    button0.setImageResource(answers[0]);

    button1.setImageResource(answers[1]);

    button2.setImageResource(answers[2]);

    button3.setImageResource(answers[3]);

}
```

Now, I am not sure how to set those ImageView resources without the app crashing. I guess there is a pretty much straightforward way to do this, but being a beginner I would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.